# How to left-align titles of dropdown menus

Tags: swiftui, drop-down-menu

In a multiplatform SwiftUI app I'm developing, I'm adding a pair of dropdown menus for minimum word length and maximum word length. I put each in an HStack so I can display the current value next to the menu title.

I want the menu titles to be flush left on my screen. However, the are centered in their frames. Here is what that looks like:

[image]

The code is below.

How would I get my 2 menu titles to be leading aligned in their frames so they are both flush left on the page?

```
                        HStack(spacing: 10){
                            Menu("Min length:") {
                                Button("None") {
                                    crosswordsState.minWordLength = nil
                                }
                                ForEach(validWordLengths, id: \.self) { value in
                                    Button(String(value)) {
                                        crosswordsState.minWordLength = value
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: menuWidth)
                            Text(crosswordsState.minWordLength.map { String($0) } ?? "None")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        HStack(spacing: 10){
                            Menu("Max word length:") {
                                Button("None") {
                                    print("None button pressed")
                                    crosswordsState.maxWordLength = nil
                                }
                                ForEach(validWordLengths, id: \.self) { value in
                                    Button(String(value)) {
                                        print(value)
                                        crosswordsState.maxWordLength = value
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: menuWidth)
                            Text(crosswordsState.maxWordLength.map { String($0) } ?? "None")
                            Spacer()
                        }
```

Comment: Try adding `alignment: .leading` to the `frame` modifier. If that doesn't work, it'd be helpful to have a [mre] to run to provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: @jnpdx, sure enough, adding `alignment: .leading` to the menu's frame does the trick. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame doesn’t have an alignment right now, so it is defaulting to center.

You can add `alignment: .leading` to the frame solve it.